# how to fill-in absolute path filename in mc?

Tags: linux, file-management, midnight-commander

Please, I cannot figure out how to fill-in absolute path filename in `mc` (Midnight commander)? I am familiar with ALT+ENTER to drop the filename onto the line, but that is just the relative filename, I would expect SHIFT+ALT+ENTER to drop **absolute path filename**, but nope :( any hints? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The following shortcuts were always available in Midnight Commander IIRC:

- `CTRL+x (CTRL no more pressed) + p` - the absolute path of the current panel
- `CTRL+x (CTRL is still being pressed) + p` - the absolute path of the opposite panel

Comment: thanks for this tip!

Comment: moreover, this works on SSH session, too! :)

Answer (score 2):

There are another combinations for `mc`:

1. Select file/folder.
2. Press `Esc+A` (it will insert path into the command line).
3. Press `Esc+Enter` (it will insert name).

Works for ssh (putty/KiTTy) session for me.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, not SHIFT+ALT+ENTER :) But you are very *close*.

I didn't know the keys either and looked it up just now in the source code for you.
I haven't tried it but it will work.

The following are lines 119 and 120 from mc's keymap.c

```
    {"PutCurrentSelected", "alt-enter; ctrl-enter"},
    {"PutCurrentFullSelected", "ctrl-shift-enter"},//<---- HERE
```

If you want to know any other keys, you can look [here](https://github.com/MidnightCommander/mc/blob/master/src/keymap.c) starting around line 100.  You don't need to be able to read 'c' as these arrays are self explanatory.

I have been using this puppy for over 20 years but didn't know these keys so thanks for adding to my `mc` skill set.

Good Luck!

Comment: I'm glad it helped you :) And thanks for sharing the direct link to the source! Unfortunately, it's not working for me, more specifically, it's not working on our server via SSH (GNU Midnight Commander 4.8.22 Built with GLib 2.58.2). On my laptop, though, it works fine (GNU Midnight Commander 4.8.26 Built with GLib 2.68.1) - using Gnome Terminal 3.38.1 - where the problem might be?

Comment: I am guessing that those keys aren't being sent through your ssh session.  I don't know how to fix this but I can guess that you can at least change the key bindings and rebuild the source with different bindings.

Comment: If I get a chance, I will play with your scenario later.

Comment: @crysman If this key doesn't work on your terminal, do `CTRL+x`, `p`, `Alt+Enter`.